After "make" my electron app can't find the sqlite3 module
I'm using electron forge, React and sqlite3 with node.js, and after i tried to make the app: "npm run make" the app works fine, but can't find the sqlite3 module, so my database don't work. He keeps giving me this error:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module '/native_modules/build/Release/node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:

C:\Users\Caio_\AppData\Local\storage_handler\app-1.0.0\resources\app.asar.webpack\renderer\main_window\index.html

My working tree:
enter image description here
After the "npm run make":
enter image description here
I noticed the file where the database should be is now an .asar file (it's located inside the resources directory). I tried somethings that i found on the internet, but couldn't solve it, like using electron-rebuild. Anybody has any ideia of what should i do to make my electron app find the sqlite3 module?
(Sorry for the bad english, i'm not native)
